# Toilet seat makes loud noise

Tags: bathroom

The toilet seat I just installed in my rental makes a loud crack when someone sits on it. What’s wrong? Could it be I didn’t tighten the bolts enough? (I fear tightening them too much!)Thank you.

Comment: Picture? Do you have the correct size? There are two general toilet/toilet seat sizes in the US - round and elongated. If you have a mismatch, it will basically work but the bumpers that are on the seat may not line up exactly with the toilet and that can result in some problems.

Comment: the bumpers are probably falling into the rim and the seat hits the rim of the bowl

Answer (score 1):

Do not confuse toilet seat bolts and the toilet bolts.

You should be careful with toilet bolts, to much and it can crack the toilet.

The toilet seat bolts are usually made of plastic. If you over-tighten those ,in worst case you have to get new bolt, but no damage to the toilet.

As for cracking, take a careful look from the side, between the toilet seat and toilet.

Are the spacers sitting on the toilet or are front ones to high (not siting on the toilet.) If yes, loosen the toilet seat bolt.